# PDF generation using dompdf

Tags: pdf-generation, dompdf

Using dompdf i generate pdf file. I am successfully generate it .
But after generating it when I open it in Foxit reader it's open very small size in 51.79% mode. When i select 'Fit width' or 125% it show properly.
When I open the pdf by default it open 125% mode can it be possible ?

I used following function:

```
function pdf_create($html, $filename)
    {
        ini_set("memory_limit", "50M");
        //define pdf store path
        $invoice_pdf_path = ABSOLUTE_PATH;
        require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
        $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
        $dompdf->load_html($html);
        $dompdf->set_paper("a4", "portrait");
        $dompdf->render();
        //$dompdf->stream("abc_out.pdf");
        $pdf = $dompdf->output();
        @file_put_contents($invoice_pdf_path . $filename . ".pdf", $pdf);

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

With dompdf 0.6 beta you can set the default view of the PDF by adding a meta tag in your HTML source code:

```
<meta name="dompdf.view" content="FitH" />
```

Possible values are "XYZ", "Fit", "FitH", "FitV", "FitR", "FitB", "FitBH", "FitBV", described [here](http://www.verypdf.com/pdfinfoeditor/pdf-tools-command-line.htm#Set_page_magnification_)

Comment: @user1429954 try $dompdf->set_default_view('FitH',array());